# Reopen this, it is not not constructive

Tags: support, reopen-request

About this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/549449/intel-i5-3rd-vs-4th-generation/549481#549481

In my opinion, this question asks a very important question about CPUs, and could help many others that want to buy any Intel CPU in the next few years.

And the answer I posted gives a solid reply that is backed up by facts announced by Intel, and proven by history about what to expect in the future of Intel's processors.

Comment: Your "facts" include a single link to Wikipedia, and only include what you "expect" will happen (your words, not mine sir).  I would think [something like this](http://superuser.com/questions/543702/why-are-newer-generation-processors-faster-even-at-the-same-clock-speed/543704#543704) has actual *factual* evidence, but even then, that point can't be used to justify an overglorified question about a shopping recommendation.

Comment: I think even though it is a shopping-like question, it is really asking about processor future., I think the last paragraph in the selected answer says it pretty nicely. -- I know that I didn't include much of past benchmarks and features comparison, but that would have been too much info for this question.

Comment: @sharp12345 - We can't predict the future.  So if your asking about what will happen in the future then its still not constructive.  Its also a shopping question which we can't even answer since the product does not actuall exist yet ( if a shopping question was on topic ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Intel is going to release the 4th generation before this summer, but is there a point for me to hang around for it?

Even if this weren't a highly subjective question to start with (whether or not something pays off is nothing any other person than the OP can decide) — what value would this question have in a few months from now?

This is one of the reasons shopping recommendations are considered off topic. They're often too localized to a specific moment in time.

And then, there's the guessing (actual quotes from the answers):

> I expect…
>
> No one knows, but probably not.
>
> … and maybe other things that no one knows about.
>
> … will the first-gen motherboards be? It's too early to say.

We don't really like that kind of guessing. We like to solve *actual* computer problems and answer based on facts and specific evidence. That being said, the question would be perfectly suited for chat.

Maybe the question could be rewritten to be generalized to Intel processor updates, and reopened given a proper answer that'd even be valid for older and newer releases alike. But without the personal shopping aspect of whether it's worth to wait or not.

Comment: Alright, I get your point, Thanks.